# How to stick window in windows os via chrome.windows.create/update

Tags: javascript, windows, macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

It's works fine for mac os, but in windows a have some terrible indents from all sides.

```
   chrome.windows.update(browser.windowId, {
     state: 'maximized',
     focused: true
   }, () => {
     chrome.windows.update(browser.windowId, {
       width: window.screen.width - sidebarWidth,
       left: leftOffsetWindow,
       height: window.screen.height
     });
   });
```

Is there any opportunity to make window stick to the left/right side with custom width in windows os?